# How do you use the context of a problem to determine what your error values mean in linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, regression-coefficients

I have been told that you must consider the context of a problem in order to determine what your error metrics are telling you.

**Question:**

What thought process would you go through to determine how good these numbers are in the exact context of this [data-set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data)?

**Context:**

I have created a linear regression model of two variables of the Iris data-set. The independent variable is "Petal Length" and the dependent variable is "Sepal Length". The error metrics have been calculated:

- **Average Sepal Length:** 5.843333
- **R-squared:**   0.703197
- **Mean Absolute Error:** 0.313679
- **Mean Squared Error:**  0.150961
- **Root Mean Squared Error:** 0.388537
- **Mean Error:** -0.88352

**Some answers I am not looking for:**

I am comfortable with the math behind some of the error metrics of linear regression, and I'm comfortable with what they represent in a big picture sort of way. For example, mean squared error is going to penalize large outliers by squaring the error. I realize that Mean Absolute Error does not do that. I also realize that Mean Absolute Error doesn't tell us which way our model is biased because it only counts magnitude, not direction. I know $R^2$ tells us how much better our model is than just predicting the average value. So these sorts of things are pretty clear and won't answer my question.

**Types of answers I am looking for:**

Based on $R^2$ it looks like my model is at least slightly better than just predicting the average. But how much better. What is the scale here?

I see that my model tends to under-estimate by 0.88 centimeters. That's about 20% of the average value, so that seems pretty bad to me. Is it really? And also, I read somewhere that bias should always be zero when in a linear regression model. Mine is not, so does that mean bad calculations somewhere?

The mean squared is 2.5% of the average. What does that mean to me (I've seen this calculation done in example problems with no explanation of why)?

If you would like to see a walk-through of my work, you can find it here. I'm trying to take notes of everthing I do for future reference:

- https://github.com/wcneill/data-science-at-home/blob/master/jupyter_practice/linear_regression_02.ipynb
- https://github.com/wcneill/data-science-at-home/blob/master/jupyter_practice/linear_regression_03.ipynb